# How should I implement login functionality on Android when I have the login API service endpoint built already?

Tags: android, authentication, google-signin

I'm trying to implement an authentication service API for my Android app. I have a prebuilt API service that I can call the login API endpoint with Retrofit 2 that will login a user. This all works fine except now I'm trying to store a login session so the user doesn't have to login every single time. I looked at a few possible options:

- Google Sign In: This seems like the easiest option, except I dont know how I will merge the Google account with my API user account IDs
- AccountManager: Seems very complex
- SharedPreferences: Seems very insecure

Comment: I see number 3 used many times, but the app will encrypt the credentials prior to storing them in shared preferences.

Comment: @dazza5000 yes that would be nice options, i use lot of time